# React Native - pass callback to another screen

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a screen with form. Now in that form there's a button that opens another screen where user selects the target option and upon selection they're navigated back to the original form (stack navigator), the reasoning is that user can also create a new option there so they go to the same UI as they would if editing options separately (which they can).

My code below solution works, **but** I get following warning:

> Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state. This can
> break usage such as persisting and restoring state. This might happen
> if you passed non-serializable values such as function, class
> instances etc. in params. If you need to use components with callbacks
> in your options, you can use 'navigation.setOptions' instead. See
> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/troubleshooting#i-get-the-warning-non-serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state
> for more details.

Now that link suggests to use `setOptions` however that is more for like adding a button to header, which is not the case, user selects the option in the target screen by clicking on the option.

Here are important parts of the code:

```typescript
// MAIN FORM SCREEN
<Button title={"Some Title"} onPress={openSelectItem}></Button>

const openSelectFish = () => {
    return navigation.navigate("ItemList", { sendItemBack: true, onGoBack: onSelectItem });
};

const onSelectItem = (item: ItemDTO) => {
    setItem(item.name); // basic useState
};

// THE OPTIONS SCREEN
const onChooseItem = (item: ItemDTO) => {
    console.log(this);
    if ((typeof route !== "object") || (typeof route.params !== "object")) return;
    if (!route.params.sendItemBack ?? true) return;
    route.params.onGoBack(item);
    return navigation.goBack();
};
// onChooseItem is then used in onPress of each option
```

Is there a better way how to send callback to the other screen?

Comment: I stumbled upon https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6827 it seems that this actually is the way, but they're warning you in case you use "state persistence or deep link" but should be good otherwise?

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#what-should-be-in-params

Comment: Why not use Context API in case you want to expose function which used in multiple screens. Passing function as route params is anti-pattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not recommended to pass a callback function via the `route params`. Judging from your code and your explanation you want to actually `pass data back to the screen on goBack`.

Instead of doing

```js
route.params.onGoBack(item);
return navigation.goBack();
```

we could just pass `item` back to `MainFormScreen` in its route params on `navigation.goBack()` and set the state directly in `MainFormScreen` in a `useEffect`. This prevents us from having to pass a function in the route params. Instead, we set the state directly in the form.

**OptionsScreen** Instead of calling `goBack`, we can use `navigate` as usual and pass `item` back to the `MainFormScreen`

```js
return navigation.navigate('MainFormScreen', { item: item })
```

**MainFormScreen** Here, we do not pass a function anymore but react on route param changes.

```js
const openSelectFish = () => {
    return navigation.navigate("ItemList", { sendItemBack: true });
};

const params = useMemo(() => route.params || {}, [route.params])

const [item, setItem] = useState()

const onSelectItem = useCallback((item: ItemDTO) => {
    setItem(item.name); // basic useState
}, [setItem]);

useEffect(() => {
   onSelectItem(params.item)
}, [params, onSelectItem])
```

Comment: Interesting, I was worried this approach would delete the states and I would end up with an empty form and back button on MainFormScreen wouldn't go back to the screen before MainFormScreen (which is not OptionsScreen) - but it *doesn't* how is it so? 
I also see you made some momoize optimization (useMemo, useCallback) - would you please explain why did you use exactly those? Thanks

Comment: Also do you know what happens with the stack from the point of the stack navigator?

Comment: This is because `navigation.navigate('RouteName') pushes a new route to the native stack navigator if it's not already in the stack, otherwise it jumps to that screen.` Since `MainFormScreen` is already on the stack and we have navigated to it from, lets say `Home`,  its back button will navigate back to home. By using navigate from `OptionsScreen` it sees that `MainFormScreen` is already on the stack so it `jumps` to it instead of `pushing` it again on the stack. (this could be done by using `push` by the way)

Comment: Both `useMemo` and `useCallback` are not necessary. I usually wrap a function that uses `setState` into a `useCallback` but this is mainly because I am used to write a lot of hooks and return values of a hook should be stable. You could leave both.

Comment: I have made a little [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/moving-between-screens-|-react-navigation) where you could test this. What do you mean by "Also do you know what happens with the stack from the point of the stack navigator?"?

Comment: by that I meant your very first comment explanation - that's exactly what I meant and that is super important information that I missed because it's hidden in fluent text in the docs - thanks very much for that and mentioning how it can be actually done if I'd want to (push) :-)